# UINavigation leftBarItem show back button and additional button

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have an app that opens with a split view controller, table on the left contains a list of customers, on the right is the users calendar. Selecting a customer from the table replaces the calendar view with a customer detail view. The left nav item in this view is the standard iOS back button which takes you back to the calendar view.

I am now working on an enhancement where we added Google maps. The maps view has a similar set up, table on left, map on right. There's a couple of options to go from the map split view back to the initial split view but bypasses displaying the calendar and goes right to showing customer details.

The project calls for the user to be able to return to the map view from the customer detail page. The flow looks something like this:

[image]

What I need to do is add a button in the navcontroller of the customer details viewcontroller that lets the user get back to the maps viewcontroller. The problem I am running into is if I add an button to navigate back to the maps I lose the default back button. I would like both to be in the navigation.

I am using this code to present the new button but self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems doesn't seem to contain the default back button.

```
if (self.fromGoogleMap) {

    NSMutableArray *barbuttonItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems];

    UIImage* imgMapBarButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img_mapbarbutton.png"];
    UIBarButtonItem* btnGoogleMap = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:imgMapBarButton landscapeImagePhone:imgMapBarButton style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(launchGoogleMapView:)];

    [barbuttonItems addObject:btnGoogleMap];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = barbuttonItems;

}
```

[image]

So how can I add a button to the navigation but retain the default back button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this line in there, it's intended to indicate that "the left items are displayed in addition to the back button."

```
self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;
```

Apple Docs reference for [leftItemsSupplementBackButton](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/leftItemsSupplementBackButton)

Comment: Sweet, that did the trick. May whatever you like a lot become available to you in abundance!

Comment: Thanks. That would be SO rep! :]

Comment: Hey, just noticed you were in Philly...I'm out in Collegeville, off of 422. Small world.

Comment: Oh wow, I'm in downingtown right near where 113 and 100 intersect.  What's your twitter handle?  The website linked from your profile is empty.

Comment: Same as my user name here.